# Delegating/ Decorating $http.get in angular

Tags: angularjs, decorator

Following page have an example for delegating debug function of $log in angular.

http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/10/07/enhance-angularjs-logging-using-decorators/

Similarly I would Like to delegate get/post functions of $http Service. So that I can log all the request that my app does.

Below is my code

```
 $provide.decorator('$http', ["$delegate", function($delegate) {
  var debugFn = $delegate.get;
  $delegate.get = function() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);

    // Prepend timestamp
    console.log(args[0]);

    // Call the original with the output prepended with formatted timestamp
    debugFn.apply(null, args)
  };

  return $delegate;
}]);
```

even though it is logging the url it throws an exception after that

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'finally' of undefined
at handleRequestFn (angular.js:17382)
at compileTemplateUrl (angular.js:8270)
at applyDirectivesToNode (angular.js:7885)
at compileNodes (angular.js:7431)
at compile (angular.js:7338)
at applyDirectivesToNode (angular.js:7808)
at compileNodes (angular.js:7431)
at compileNodes (angular.js:7443)
at compile (angular.js:7338)
at angular.js:1630
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return the result (promise) of the original get function:

```
$delegate.get = function() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);

    // Prepend timestamp
    console.log(args[0]);

    // Call the original with the output prepended with formatted timestamp
    return debugFn.apply(null, args)
};
```

Comment: @eladcon the answer is incomplete how to do or what was changed!
**how to return the result (promise) of the original get function**

Answer (score 3):

> So that I can log all the request that my app does.

You could use **Interceptors** instead (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

---

One useful link with examples - http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/